# Is there a tool for creating animation with HTML?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a tool for creating animation with **HTML**, or just any other language that can be added with HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many languages that can aid in 'animation' behavior.  Depending on what type/level of animation you want, will point you in the right direction.  If you want just mouse-over animation, javascript and CSS are your friends.  If you want something more sophisticated you'll want to look at Flash (but that's a beast of its own).  For the most part, HTML5 (canvas) has some nice 'animation' behaviors that you can easily invoke with JavaScript.  You might want to start there.  Furthermore, if you want a more specific answer you might clarify what type of animation behavior you are after (examples included).

Comment: I've found jQuery (a javascript "library") quite useful for moving, fading, and coloring blocks of HTML (divs or spans).

Comment: Yes jQuery is def the buzz word these days.  For cross-browser support and application building I'd recommend dojo.  There are others, but I know jQuery and Dojo seem to be pretty dominant.